# Implement a simple dropdown menu only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been practicing CSS for a while ago and trying to implement a simple drop-down menu without using either bootstrap or jQuery.

The problem is, I cannot fully mimic the drop-down menu looks like the following image below.

**Expecting Result**

[image]

**Current Result**

[image]

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <ul id="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a href="#travel">Travel</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a href="#food">Food</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Please check out the fiddle to see styling](https://jsfiddle.net/JeffMinsungKim/1Lztowea/)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use purely CSS? Why not some Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: @RobertDickey No, there isn't any particular reason. I thought I could mimic the menu right away by only using CSS. Is usage of JavaScript mandatory for this case?

Comment: Is the :hover psuedo-class that displays the actual menu going to work on mobile?

Comment: What is your exact problem? The styling of the three-dash-menu item?

Comment: If your "question" is *"I can't style it as I want"*, you're simply a client asking for free programming services and your question is *off-topic* on [SO]. If your question is in the form of: *"this property does **this** according to specs, but in my case it does **the other**"*, you're a programmer learning and your question is *on-topic* here, as it will help others learn/understand what wasn't clear for you as well.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I understand what you're saying, and I'm fully aware of that. But I'm a person who is learning CSS at the moment, and sometimes people get bogged down, during practices because of a small thing could not be resolved by themselves. Instead of asking someone for doing all my work, at least I've tried some workaround by myself to get some little help before I post the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: First of all, there's no such thing as a *"simple"* dropdown menu. It's one of the most complex elements in a website, along with accordions, tabs or sliders. It uses different concepts on touch vs desktop devices, which are hard to reconcile. Animations should feel smooth and natural, ideally one should be able to control and reverse them (think touch gestures); links should feel friendly and smooth, responding to touch/hover. Toggle transition, menu transitions and link hover/activate transitions - each have plenty of examples here and can take a while to master.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thank you for your in-depth information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were quite a few inaccuracies in your fiddle demo so I figured I would just rewrite this to look like your desired result and then you could go from there.  The theory behind a css dropdown menu is that the containing element will be have a certain position (in this case I have positioned it to relative) and the dropdown menu will have a position of absolute inside the containing element and a display of none.  Then when you hover on the containing element the dropdown will have a display of block so here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve.

```css
#menu{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  /*font size 0 removes white space from inline block elements add font size to  the dropdown menu*/
  font-size:0;
}
#menu .menu-toggle {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  border:1px solid rgb(220,220,220);
  display:inline-block;
}
#menu .menu-toggle span{
  display:block;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #33333D;
}

#dropdown-menu{
  display:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  border:1px solid rgb(220,220,220);
  font-size:16px;
}
#menu:hover #dropdown-menu{
  display:block;
}
#dropdown-menu li a{
  display:block;
  padding:5px 15px;
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menu-toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a href="#travel">Travel</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a href="#food">Food</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) I would just add you can achieve the border effect in the OP's original image by overlapping an opaque toggle button with the top of the border of the dropdown. Something like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtpebs1x/49)

Comment: Thank you, Steve. It helped me a lot!

Comment: @Anders I like your way but it seems like the dropdown has some losing focus issue from time to time when I hover the toggle.

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim Whoops missed that, updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtpebs1x/66/) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="menu-area">
  <div id="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <ul id="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
     <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a href="#travel">Travel</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a href="#food">Food</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>



.menu-area {
   width: 220px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: right;
}
#menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
a.menu-toggle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s;
}
#menu:hover a.menu-toggle {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
a.menu-toggle span {
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: #555;
}
ul#dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 218px;
    transition: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
}
#menu:hover ul#dropdown-menu {
    top: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul#dropdown-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    display: block;
}
ul#dropdown-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .3s;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul#dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: #666;
}
```